# creating a loop from a list of maps flutter

Tags: list, flutter

Im trying to create a loop that will print the ISBN and it's Values.

this is a sample a list.

```
"BooksISBN": [
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_13",
                        "identifier": "9783846035672"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ISBN_10",
                        "identifier": "384603567X"
                    }
                ],
```

expected reslut

```
ISBN_13 : 9783846035672
ISBN_10 : 384603567X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out

```
      var value = {
  "BooksISBN": [
    {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9783846035672"
    },
    {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "384603567X"
    }
  ],
};
  value.forEach((key, val) { 
    for(var i = 0; i<val.length; i++ )
    print("${val[i]["type"]}: ${val[i]["identifier"]}");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isbns.forEach((isbn) {
    print("${isbn['type']} : ${isbn['identifier']}");
})
```